# angular ui modal bootstrap sass not showing overlay or not visible overlay

Tags: angularjs, sass, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal

I'm using a modal angular ui 
all it's ok but the overlay it's
not visible or too fade.

I'm using bootstrap  sass and I've tried
with:

```
$modal-backdrop-bg: red !default;
$modal-backdrop-opacity : 0.5 !default;
```

with no lucky

[image: my modal]

My goal is show my nice modal 
with a dark overlay :)

Comment: did you find any alternative to solve this issue?

Comment: 3.1.1 :( and I dont know whay on earth there are three votes to close the post ^^

Comment: me neither, haters gonna hate and here in SO are many, to me is a valid question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to override the bootstrap modal class with this

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position:absolute !important;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#000000;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

I also added this class for centering it

```
.modal-center{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 18.5%;
    z-index: 1050;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: -10%;
}
```

this is the template I'm using:

```
<div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" ng-click="cancel()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">some title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a class="hand-cursor" ng-click="ok($index)">{{ item.label }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="text-center">
                Selected: <b>{{ selected.item.label }}</b>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
```

and this is the code for the $modal instance

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'sometemplate.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceController',
    windowClass:'modal-center modal fade in',
    resolve: {
        items: function () {
            scope.items = ModelerMenusource; // <-- a simple array with the list of items
            return scope.items;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are the man bro :P just a thing you shoul add to background-color and opacity !important

Answer (score 1):

I think I've encountered the very same problem.

[image]

Eventually I decided to use the version it was tested against.

Try using **3.1.1.** :)

Comment: thx for the tip I've just seen it but now I've got bootstrap-sass 3.3.1 and I can't use an old version for the app because of a modal ! :)

Comment: I'm sorry for not being more helpful. Maybe you can try temporarily switch to 3.1.1, see what's changed and make one or two overrides?